# Get dropdown under button in Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Unfortunately I can't figure it out.

Hopefully a css/bootstrap guru can show me the way in the darkness.

http://fmjd.org/sandbox/

[image]
When clicking at "Dropdown" I expect the menu to be opened below the button. 
But it goes to the left.
What is wrong in the choice of classes/css?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all you need to force yourself to check if webpage is validating properly in [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input). Your code had 8 issues. I've corrected those first. Then I checked on Bootstrap's official documentation how to do [Dropdowns and Button Groups](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns). I've almost completly mimicked the documentation code snippet, resulting in:

[image: Result]

Entire code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>
            5
        </title>
        <!-- Le styles -->
        <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js">
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-small">Book</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-small">China</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-small">Computers</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-small">Electronica</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-small btn-primary">GSM</button>
                <div class="btn-group">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-small btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            Dropdown 
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Action</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Another action</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Something else here</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-small">Software</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Good luck!